PSA: Warning about Electron Cash wallet
There have been multiple questions / reports now about the Electron Cash wallet stealing users BCC. There has been a official warning as well on the Electrum website:

The person who distributes the Electron Cash binaries has decided to
  remain anonymous, and uses the fake name "Jonald Fyookball" in order
  to sign Electron Cash binaries. Thus, if these binaries contain code
  that is designed to steal your bitcoins, the author of the theft will
  be anonymous and walk away safely with your funds.

Furthermore, the Electum Cash wallet is known to copy the wallet data from the official Electrum wallet, so there should even be more reason to be worried.
I suggest that we sticky a warning on the top of meta that users should not use this wallet or at least be very careful when doing so, knowing that it may empty their account.

I suggest that we sticky a warning on the top of meta that users should not use this wallet or at least be very careful when doing so, knowing that it may empty their account. I'm leery of passing along a message like this without having some kind of firsthand verification. How do we know that those users didn't have some kind of unrelated banking trojan on their computers?

I heard that that was a fake Electron Cash wallet.
